# Custom Table Cell doesn't show any content- Swift 2

Tags: ios, uitableview, maps, swift2

I am trying to make a custom table view cell to appear when I press a button on an annotation on my app. When I press the button, an empty cell appears and I can't find out what's wrong about it. What do you suggest? 
thanks in advance

class ViewController: UIViewController,
 MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,  UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

```
struct MyData {
    var imagy:UIImage
    var title:String
    var details:String
}

var tableData: [MyData] = []

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var mapItemData:MKMapItem!

let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"


//TableViewDataSource functions
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{ return 1 }




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Create a new cell with the reuse identifier of our prototype cell
    // as our custom table cell class
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell") as! TableViewController
    // Set the first row text label to the firstRowLabel data in our current array item
    cell.imagy.image = tableData[indexPath.row].imagy
    // Set the second row text label to the secondRowLabel data in our current array item
    cell.title.text = tableData[indexPath.row].title
    // Set the second row text label to the secondRowLabel data in our current array item
    cell.details.text = tableData[indexPath.row].details
    // Return our new cell for display

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    return cell


}

 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
    sender: AnyObject?){
        // Set any data to be shown on the table view here
}

var picture:[UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "pic1.jpg")!,
    //UIImage(named: "pic2.jpg")!,
    //UIImage(named: "pic3.jpg")!,
    //UIImage(named: "pic4.jpg")!,
   // UIImage(named: "pic5.jpg")!,
   // UIImage(named: "pic6.jpg")!,
    //UIImage(named: "pic7.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "pic8.jpg")!,    ]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

And this is the TableView Class:

class TableViewController: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var imagy: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var details: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var exit: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called only when your `tableView.dataSource` is already set. You put this:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so of course there's nothing in your table. It's like you put your key in the house then close the door. Put them in `viewDidLoad` instead.

Comment: thank you for your reply. The problem is though, when I put them in viewdidload, i get an error "Ambiguous use of tableview numberofrowsinsection"

Comment: did you create a proper `IBOutlet` of your table view?

Comment: It's like when you create: `@IBOutlet weak var imagy: UIImageView!`. Do you have anything like this: `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`?

Comment: I realized what you meant by IBOutlet, and I knew how to create the outlets for the image and the title but I didn't have one for the tableView. I just created one now and it compiles but I get a BAD execution on tableview.datasource = self

Comment: Hmm I think it is not enough if you simply write " @IBOutlet ...."  you have to link it manually somehow, that probably what is causing the bad execution

Comment: Oh of course you need to link them! You must Ctrl then drag what you want into source file like [this image](http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/CoreData2-10.png).

Comment: ok, final question. If you do that but it just doesn't link, what could be the potential issue?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't link? When you successfully created an IBOutlet, there will be a gray dot next to it.

Comment: There is a grey-empty dot, I think that when it successfully links, it has a grey full dot.

Comment: Sorry late reply, yes success = full dot, not linked = empty dot. If you write an IBOutlet in code, an empty dot appears until you drag it in tableview in storyboard to connect them.